# ckeditor leave html double quotes code &#34; alone

Tags: ckeditor

In my ckeditor I need to leave &#34; alone. Right now when I go to source view, enter &#34; and return to WYSIWYG, and back to source view, it turns &#34; to 
&quot;, which is breaking things.

Same thing happens when ckeditor loads for the first time.

Specifically the string I want left alone is.

```
<a class="someLink" href="/somePlace" onclick="atpto_tNav.toggleBlind('2459',0,'upc(2459,&#34;parentPriKeyID=6&#34;)','ntid_tNav2459',event);return false">Blarg</a>
```

I have tried

```
CKEDITOR.config.basicEntities = false;
CKEDITOR.config.entities = false;
CKEDITOR.config.entities_greek = false;
CKEDITOR.config.entities_latin = false;
CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true; 
CKEDITOR.config.entities_additional = "#34";
```

On a side note I'm loading ckeditor dynamically with javascript. It generally works great except for this part.

Answer (score 0):

Not a fix for ckeditor, but I found that this will also work...

using \x22  instead of &#34;

so if I use this string instead....

```
<a class="someLink" href="/somePlace" onclick="atpto_tNav.toggleBlind('2459',0,'upc(2459,\x22parentPriKeyID=6\x22)','ntid_tNav2459',event);return false">Blarg</a>
```

It works and plays nice with ckeditor

Answer (score 0):

On my CKEditor v4 `'` is *never* converted to `&quot;`. Maybe need to update to latest version.

*More infos :*
After testing it came out that `config.entities_additional` is efficient only if `CKEDITOR.config.entities` is let to default (true).

It's an **additional** feature.
The default value converts single quote to `&#39;`
If you want to add double quotes :
`config.entities_additional = '#34,#39';`
(if #39 is removed, single quotes are no longer converted)

HTML numbers `(&#39;)` can be interesting for symbols you want to "protect" for one reason or another but which doesn't have their HTML name `(&apos;)` counterpart.
*example* : the `+` sign is `&#43;` but doesn't have a name version.
But beware, some codes make cke buggy : for example `#160 (== &nbsp;)` let the cke field filled with `undefined` :)